# How i can hide an item menu when logged in (in joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla2.5

In Joomla 2.5, I need to hide the item menu "reserved area" after logged in.

Any trick?

If it's impossible to get achieved by configuration, could you give me any suggestion about the code I have to modify?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the menu item to **Guest** Access Level.

```
Menus -> *Menu_Name -> *Menu_Item -> Access: Guest
```

Reference: [Allowing Guest-Only Access to Menu Items and Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules).

Comment: Hi, to clarify your answer, I think you want to first create a user group 'Guest' (as per section 5: Allowing Guest-Only Access to Menu Items and Modules of the good reference you provided, https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules